# LESS CSS Comments in the right place

Tags: html, css, wordpress, comments, less

I am using LESS CSS for WordPress Theme development. I have just noticed that when I compile the LESS files to CSS all of the comments placed inside LESS file are added to the top of the CSS file (and not on the right line)... is there any way to avoid this? I am using Less for mac as a compiler also tried the simpLess but the same problem occurs.

Comment: I use CodeKit to compile and do not have this issue.

Comment: I have just tried CodeKit but I still have this problem, maybe because my style.less imports few other LESS files, all of the comments from the imported file are stacked together at the top :|

Comment: If I put a comment inside the "last" selector the comment is placed in the right place but if I have something like this: `#wrapper { /* comment */ #selector { ...some css... } /* comment */ #selector { ...some css... }}` Both comments will be placed at the top just bellow at the wrapper. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not ideal, and certainly against convention, I place my comments inside the style definition.

eg:

```
.style {

    /* Comment for .style */
    ...style definition...

    .inner-style {
        /* Comment for .inner-style */
        ...style definition...
    }
}
```